# Split table in Entity Framework into multiple entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

Here's the problem. I have table **User** which have quite a few fields. What I want to do is split this table into multiple entities like this:

```
User
  -> GeneralDetails
  -> CommunicationDetails
  -> Address

etc.
```

All goes well when extracting some fields from **User** into **GeneralDetails**. However, when I try to do the same thing for **CommunicationDetails** EF blows up and require to establish one-to-one relationship between **GeneralDetails** and **CommunicationDetails**.

Sample entities definition:

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string SomeField1 { get; set; }
    public int SomeField2 { get; set; }

    public virtual GeneralDetails GeneralDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual CommunicationDetails CommunicationDetails { get; set; }
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class GeneralDetails {   
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get;set; }
}

public class CommunicationDetails { 
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string DeviceToken { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get;set; }
}

public class Address {  
    [Key]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    public string City { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get;set; }
}
```

Sample mapping:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
             HasRequired(user => user.GeneralDetails).
             WithRequiredPrincipal(details => details.User);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
             HasRequired(user => user.CommunicationDetails).
             WithRequiredPrincipal(details => details.User);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().
             HasRequired(user => user.Address).
             WithRequiredPrincipal(details => details.User);

modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<GeneralDetails>().ToTable("Users");
modelBuilder.Entity<Address>().ToTable("Users");
```

Why on earth EF want this relationship? Is there any way this could be solved?

Comment: It does seem that your users table has been correctly normalised, once properly normalised means you should be able to get them as one entity. The fact your splitting this table in three suggest that you may just want three different tables in your db aswell. This is just a suggestion please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: @Srb1313711 I have to disagree. One of the main points of an OR/M is to map objects to the database. The shape of the objects should be driven by the application domain, whilst the database should be, database shaped. Case and point, many to many relationships in databases necessitate an association table, which normally should not map to a class in the application.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to actually do this is by Complex Types rather than entities. Its actually a more common problem than you think.

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelbuilder.ComplexType<CommunicationDetails>();
        modelbuilder.ComplexType<GeneralDetails>();
        modelbuilder.ComplexType<Address>();
        modelbuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a full example of this?